# Translate MongoDB Query to Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to use this request in java using mongodb driver

```
db.product.update({"orders._id":ObjectId("59328d583c5179156cb9c241")},
    {
      $set:{
      "orders.$.description":"ccc"
      }
    })
```

**my object**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59328d543c5179156cb9c240"), 
    "fullName" : "aaa", 
    "orders" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59328d583c5179156cb9c241"), 
            "description" : "bbb"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result**

> { 
>       "_id" : ObjectId("59328d543c5179156cb9c240"), 
>       "fullName" : "aaa", 
>       "orders" : [
>           {
>               "_id" : ObjectId("59328d583c5179156cb9c241"), 
>               "description" : "ccc"
>           }
>       ] }

**what i have tried**

```
BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("orders._id", myId));
set.append("$set", new BasicDBObject("description", "ccc");
product.update(searchQueryByOrderId, set);
```

> **driver used** :
>   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver

Comment: So what looks different in the code you can run in the shell to the code in Java? Take a look. Should you not be using the same aguments? What comes after `$set`? Does it look the same? So make the next key name the same.

Comment: Think like this. When you see `{}` in the shell you insead use `DBObject()` or preferably `Document`. And where you see `[]` then that is a standard Java list. It's that simple.